# Here Map Swift SDK Calculation of Route Always Error

Tags: here-api, here-ios

I am using Here Maps's Premium SDK for iOS, on Xcode 8.2, Swift 3. Currently, I could display the maps, find my current location, and center the map to my current location.

However, when I am trying to calculate the route using NMACoreRouter, it always return error. The following are parts of my codes:

```
private var nma_core_router: NMACoreRouter!

...

nam_core_router = NMACoreRouter.init()

...

let geo1 = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: lat1, longitude: lng1)
let geo2 = NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: lat2, longitude: lng2)

let pt1 = NMAWaypoint(geoCoordinates: geo1!)
let pt2 = NMAWaypoint(geoCoordinates: geo2!, waypointType: NMAWaypointType.stopWaypoint)

let stops = [pt1!, pt2!]

let mode = NMARoutingMode(routingType: NMARoutingType.shortest, transportMode: NMATransportMode.bike, routingOptions: 0)

nma_core_router.calculateRoute(withStops: stops, routingMode: mode!) {
            (routeResult: NMARouteResult?, error: NMARoutingError?) in

   if error == nil {
       // handle routing results
   } else {
       //====> always here, no matter how accurate the coordinates were
   }
}
```

The error always appear and has NMARoutingError

could someone tell me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Due to: 
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/group--nma--route.html#topic-apiref__nmaroutingtype the routingtype "shortest" is only supported for cars. Since you try to calculate a bike route, please use routingtype "fastest" instead.